A seeming example of a group whose subgroup lattice is lower semimodular but not consistent: where's my error?
Corollary 5.3.12 in Schmidt's "subgroup lattices of groups" states that if groups $A,B$ have lower semimodular subgroup lattices, then so does their direct product $A \times B$.
This paper examines groups whose subgroup lattices are consistent, ie. for any two subgroups $A,B \le G$, if $A$ is join-irreducible in $G$ then $\left<A \cup B\right>$ is join-irreducible in the interval lattice $[B,G]$.The authors claim that every lower semimodular subgroup lattice must be consistent.
Here's my problem, though: both $S_3$ and $C_2$ have lower semimodular (in fact: even modular), subgroup lattices, and lower semimodularity does indeed seem to hold for $S_3 \times C_2$, which is isomorphic with the dihedral group of order 12.
However, in this diagram, and every other diagram I was able to find, $\left<s\right>$ and $\left<sr\right>$ are both join-irreducible (in fact: even atoms), but $\left<s,sr\right>=D_{12}$ is join irreducible neither in $[\left<s\right>,D_{12}]$ nor $[\left<sr\right>,D_{12}]$. Hence $D_{12}$ doesn't seem to be consistent.
I seriously doubt any of the linked sources contain factual errors, so... where's my mistake?

Please write an informative title.... one that deals the the specific question.

This question concerns the implication (a)$\Rightarrow$(b) of Theorem 8.1 of 
Karen M. Gragg, Joseph P.S. Kung
Consistent dually semimodular lattices
Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A
Volume 60, Issue 2, 1992,246-263.
This theorem is wrong. The authors acknowledge this in 
Karen M. Gragg, Joseph P.S. Kung
Erratum "Consistent dually semimodular lattices''
Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A
Volume 71, Issue 1, 1995,173.
The relevant lines from the erratum are:
Several people, including A. Vethamanickam, have pointed out to the
authors an error on p. 261. In Theorem 8.1, the assertion that properties (a) and (b) are equivalent is incorrect, and there exist subgroup lattices which are dually semimodular but not consistent. Counterexamples are
lattices of subgroups of the dihedral groups of order $2pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

